# How can I be notified about State Machine Completion?

Tags: spring-statemachine

I have a State Configuration with a pseudo-endstate configured. I expected that the state machine would be completed when reaching that state, but I'm missing a way of getting notified about it.

I've registered a StateMachineListener, but it doesn't get notified about completion of a state machine.

Answer (score 0):

Ok - I finally found out.

For a State Machine to stop, a state with pseudostate END must be defined. When this state is reached, a StateMachineListener will be notified that the machine is stopped.

Beneath is the outline of the spring configuration, I use. Some of the details have been left out for brievity.

```
@Override
public void configure(StateMachineStateConfigurer<String, String> states) throws Exception {
    states
            .withStates()
            .initial("WAITING")
            .state("FAILED", fail(), null)
            .state("SUCCESS", success(), null)
            .end("COMPLETED")

    ;
}
```

In the transition configuration, you do like this:

```
@Override
public void configure(StateMachineTransitionConfigurer<String, String> transitions) throws Exception {
    transitions
            .withExternal().source("FAILED").target("COMPLETED")
            .and().withExternal().source("SUCCESS").target("COMPLETED")
    ;
}
```

Comment: Oh yeah, that looks about right. Noticed this question yesterday evening and was just about to ask what your machine config were(for the original question). Was it a case that when you originally said that you had "pseudo-endstate configured", you actually didn't have that?

Comment: I thought i had an end state, but it was malconfigured. I did this:
states
                .withStates()
                .initial("WAITING")
                .state("FAILED", fail(), null)
                .end("FAILED")

That seemed not to work. The state had to be declared as end state before being listed as a State.

Comment: So it seems like that either a state is declared with the state() method OR with one of the pseudo states like end() - not both. At least only the first declaration has effect. I could not read that out of the documentation.